# Pyhton3 Django problem with stattic files and javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.7

in this html code

```
<button id="play" onclick="playOrPauseSong()"><img style = "height:160%; width: 160%" src="{% static 'img/play.png' %}"/></button>
```

when user click on button the funcution playOrPauseSong() will change the button image
as in the js code

```
function playOrPauseSong()
{
    var $ = django.jQuery
    if (song.paused) {
        song.src = "song1.mp3";
        song.play();
        $("#play img").attr("src", 'stop.png');
    } else {
        song.pause();
        $("#play img").attr("src", 'play.png');
    }
}
```

but the button not changes img correctly in Django 
what is the problem